# Unable to install Let's Encrypt certificate on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, certificates, letsencrypt, certbot

I am trying to install a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate to my website using Securing Apache with Let's Encrypt on CentOS 7.

My web server is (include version): Apache (cPanel)

My hosting provider is: GoDaddy

[followed this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-7) for that and STEP-1 and STEP-2 were successful

with the understanding that no firewall has been setup in my VPS

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install httpd mod_ssl python-certbot-apache
sudo systemctl start httpd
systemctl status httpd
curl www.example.com ((Note: works))       
sudo certbot --apache -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

This last command generates an error, as follows:

```
sudo: certbot: command not found
```

I tried to install certbot by

```
sudo yum install certbot
```

and installed successfully

```
  Installed:
  certbot.noarch 0:0.27.1-1.el7

Dependency Installed:
  audit-libs-python.x86_64 0:2.8.1-3.el7_5.1         checkpolicy.x86_64 0:2.5-6.el7                       libcgroup.x86_64 0:0.41-15.el7
  libsemanage-python.x86_64 0:2.5-11.el7             policycoreutils-python.x86_64 0:2.5-22.el7           pyOpenSSL.x86_64 0:0.13.1-3.el7
  python-IPy.noarch 0:0.75-6.el7                     python-cffi.x86_64 0:1.6.0-5.el7                     python-enum34.noarch 0:1.0.4-1.el7
  python-idna.noarch 0:2.4-1.el7                     python-ndg_httpsclient.noarch 0:0.3.2-1.el7          python-ply.noarch 0:3.4-11.el7
  python-pycparser.noarch 0:2.14-1.el7               python-requests.noarch 0:2.6.0-1.el7_1               python-requests-toolbelt.noarch 0:0.8.0-1.el7
  python-six.noarch 0:1.9.0-2.el7                    python-urllib3.noarch 0:1.10.2-5.el7                 python-zope-component.noarch 1:4.1.0-3.el7
  python-zope-event.noarch 0:4.0.3-2.el7             python-zope-interface.x86_64 0:4.0.5-4.el7           python2-acme.noarch 0:0.27.1-1.el7
  python2-certbot.noarch 0:0.27.1-1.el7              python2-configargparse.noarch 0:0.11.0-1.el7         python2-cryptography.x86_64 0:1.7.2-2.el7
  python2-future.noarch 0:0.16.0-6.el7               python2-josepy.noarch 0:1.1.0-1.el7                  python2-mock.noarch 0:1.0.1-9.el7
  python2-parsedatetime.noarch 0:2.4-5.el7           python2-pyasn1.noarch 0:0.1.9-7.el7                  python2-pyrfc3339.noarch 0:1.0-2.el7
  python2-requests.noarch 0:2.6.0-0.el7              python2-six.noarch 0:1.9.0-0.el7                     pytz.noarch 0:2016.10-2.el7
  setools-libs.x86_64 0:3.3.8-2.el7

Complete!
```

I  again tried to request an SSL certificate for my domain.

```
   sudo certbot --apache -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

this time it's  returning

```
   Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
   The requested apache plugin does not appear to be installed
```

/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

```
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,542:DEBUG:certbot.main:certbot version: 0.27.1
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,542:DEBUG:certbot.main:Arguments: ['--apache', '-d', 'example.com', '-d', 'www.example.com']
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,543:DEBUG:certbot.main:Discovered plugins: PluginsRegistry(PluginEntryPoint#manual,PluginEntryPoint#null,PluginEntryPoint#standalone,Plugi$
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,611:DEBUG:certbot.log:Root logging level set at 20
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,611:INFO:certbot.log:Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,613:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Requested authenticator apache and installer apache
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,613:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:No candidate plugin
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,614:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Selected authenticator None and installer None
```

**Note: I replaced example.com with my actual domain**

**UPDATE 1**

I tried with

```
  sudo yum install python-certbot-apache
```

it is returning

```
  --> Finished Dependency Resolution
  Error: Package: python2-certbot-apache-0.27.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: mod_ssl
  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
   You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: [This URL](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centosrhel7-apache) lists the package name as 'python2-certbot-apache' instead of 'python-certbot-apache' as specified in the question. Maybe you have the wrong package?

Comment: @RubberStamp, Thank you for the Quick Response. I'm not sure how to activate the plugin a2enmod. Can you please let me know that?

Comment: @Haxiel, Thank you for the quick response.I tried with "sudo yum install python-certbot-apache" as you have suggested and update the result in the question .Please check and let me know what to do now.

Comment: Sorry... my comment was incorrect.... the "certbot-apache" plugin seems to enable automatic settings within an apache configuration.  The Debian package comes with a Centos configuration template which is stored at `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache/centos-options-ssl-apache.conf` on my installation.  Sorry about the confusion... I usually shut down all webservices for the few seconds it takes to update the certs using the built in webserver...  try running certbot without the `--apache` option and add the `--dry-run` option to see if things work.

Comment: And, you'll definitely need `mod_ssl` if you plan on using the certs to secure web traffic with apache.

Comment: Thanks for checking. So yum is complaining that you don't have the `mod_ssl` package. That should have been installed with the first yum install command, but can you try installing that once again? The command would be `sudo yum install mod_ssl`.

Comment: If cPanel still works the same as the last time I used it, it compiles its own Apache from source (they call it EasyApache) and the `certbot` Apache automatic configuration plugin packaged for CentOS will probably not work with EadyApache.  It looks like [cPanel has their own plugin to enable Lets Encrypt](https://blog.cpanel.com/announcing-cpanel-whms-official-lets-encrypt-with-autossl-plugin/).

Comment: @current_user Is there anything else I could do for you? I use Let's Encrypt and Apache2 for years, so feel free to ask me anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the problem with doing this?:

```
sudo yum install mod_ssl

sudo a2enmod ssl
```

(restart apache then)